# Swift, приложение для iOS. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки во всплывающем окне программа начиналась заново

Tags: ios, swift

Я пишу приложение, в котором:

1. Выводится пример из случайных чисел.
2. Введя в поле ответов число, пользователь должен нажать на кнопку "проверить", и получить всплывающее окно с результатом.
3. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку во всплывающем окне, и программа  должна начинаться заново. Именно с реализацией последнего пункта у меня возникли затруднения.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // первый операнд
    let randomNum1 = UInt8(arc4random_uniform(100))
    // второй операнд
    let randomNum2 = UInt8(arc4random_uniform(100))
    // лейбл, где должен выводиться пример
    @IBOutlet weak var task: UILabel!
    // функция, которая выводит на лейбл пример
    @IBAction func changeTaskText(_ sender: UIButton){
        task.text = ("\(randomNum1) + \(randomNum2)")
    }
    // лейбл, на который должен выводиться ответ
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!
 // функция, которая выводит на лейбл ответ
    @IBAction func changeAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
answer.text = answer.text! + String(sender.tag)
    }
    // кнопка проверки ответа
    @IBAction func Check() {

        /* переменная, хранящая в себе данные
           о примере и сравниваемая с ответом пользователя */
        let taskAnswer = randomNum1 + randomNum2
        switch answer.text {
            /* всплывающее окно при неправильном
             ответе (введенные данные меньше
             необходимого результата */
        case _ where  UInt8(answer.text!)! < taskAnswer:

            let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Your answer isn't correct", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
              self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            /* всплывающее окно при неправильном
             ответе (введенные данные больше
             необходимого результата */
        case _ where UInt8(answer.text!)! > taskAnswer:

            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Your answer isn't correct", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

             // всплывающее окно при правильном ответе
        case _ where UInt8(answer.text!)! == taskAnswer:

            let alert3 = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulations!", message: "Your answer is correct", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert3.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert3, animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "программа начиналась заново"? Можно очистить поля для ввода данных, а можно принудительно перезапустить приложение. Я подозреваю, что вам все-таки первый вариант нужен.

Comment: Да, вы правы. 
Мне нужен первый вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить несколькими способами, но самый простой вот этот:

У вас в коде у метода present есть такой параметр, как completion. Туда можно подставить замыкание.

Например:

```
let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Your answer isn't correct", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: {
    self.textfield.text = ""; // Очищаете тот аутлет, который вам нужен, от текста.
})
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Phantogramm, если ответ помог, ткните в галку рядом с ответом, чтоб отметить его, как принятый.